# How automatic is the Django permission on models?

Tags: python, django

I am currently practicing the permission modules of Django

These are my models:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Teacher(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def name(self):
        return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.first_name,
                                    self.middle_name,
                                    self.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name()


class Section(models.Model):
    """
    This model must only be manipulated by its respective teacher
    """

    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    """
    This model must only be manipulated by its respective teacher
    """

    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def name(self):
        return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.first_name,
                                    self.middle_name,
                                    self.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name()


class Subject(models.Model):
    """
    This model must only be manipulated by its respective student
    """

    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in my django-admin I created groups like:

```
principal  # Can change, add and delete Teacher Model
teacher  # Can change, add and delete Student and Section Model
school_admin  # Can change, add and delete School Model
student  # Can change, add and delete Subject Model
```

In my views.py, I tried authenticating and logging-in a user then logging-in user that has a teacher group then creating a School object like:

```
def index(request):
    template = 'login.html'
    user = request.user
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context_dict = {'login_form': login_form}

    if user.is_authenticated():
        groups = user.groups
        print 'User:'
        print user
        if groups.filter(name='teacher').exists():
            print 'Teachers'
            # The code below will save even though it is not in its permission
            School.objects.create(name='DPS', address='Some Address')
        return HttpResponse("Login")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if login_form.is_valid():
            username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
            # print (login_form.cleaned_data)
            # user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            user = authenticate(email=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong Username Password")

    return render(request, template, context_dict)
```

The School object got created.. But I expected it to not be created because the logged-in user does not have the permission to create School objects.. Am I missing something to enable what I'm expecting without doing much coding? Or do I really have to put a conditional statement with the use of Groups and Permissions manually on the views?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the line

```
School.objects.create(name='DPS', address='Some Address')
```

is an independent expression. As long as it passed the teacher filter, it will execute in the code because it has no idea about the context or the permission. You can simply use conditionals to achieve what you want.

Comment: As I thought so... Thanks!